# What does Cocoa do with color components outside the range [0.0 .. 1.0]?

Tags: cocoa

If I attempt to set a pixel color to values outside that range, will the bitmap remember the value, or clamp it to the range?  If it remembers the value, I assume it still clamps to display it.

Answer (score 1):

Values below 0.0 are treated as 0.0. Values above 1.0 are treated as 1.0.

Comment: That doesn't address whether it clamps the value before it is put in the bitmap, or only when it is displayed.  For instance, if I assign a red value of 2.0 to a pixel, then later apply CIControls to reduce contrast, will the result be a reduction from 2.0, or from 1.0?

I know that I can put any float value into a CIColorCube map and it retains the value.  It clamps it when the filter is used.  I'm just curious if bitmaps retain "out of bounds" values.